# Compare list items in pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a `list` say `l = [1, 2, 3, 4]` how do I compare `l[0] < l[1] < l[2] < l[3]` in pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about this:

```
l == sorted(l)
```

Comment: But if you only want to check that `l` is sorted, you'll pay the `O(n*log(n))` cost of sorting a list while it could have been in `O(n)`.

Comment: depends on the size of l, if l < 10k you should not worry

Comment: Really thsi simple? looks pythonic. for me len(l) is always less than 5 so no O(n*log(n)) worry. Thanks

Comment: I don't like the semantics of this solution. Either you want to check if the list is sorted, and you do it with a proper algorithm, or you want it to be sorted, and you sort it. What are you gonna write next, `if l != sorted(l): l.sort()`? Just write `l.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a general approach, that consists in zipping the list with itself, with an offset.

In this situation, you can wrap it up in a list comprehension:

```
[a < b for a, b in zip(l[:-1], l[1:])]
# [l[0] < l[1], l[1] < l[2], ...]
```

This will give you a list of booleans.
To check if the list is globally sorted, you can use `all`:

```
all([a < b for a, b in zip(l[:-1], l[1:])])
```

But then, you don't need to build the actual list, a generator is enough:

```
all(a < b for a, b in zip(l[:-1], l[1:]))
```

Notice that the square brackets `[]` are dropped: the elements of the comprehensions will be evaluated lazily, which will avoid the creation of a useless list.

This solution has a `O(n)` complexity: you iterate twice over `l` with the `zip`, then once over the zipped values with `all`.

On the other hand, `l == sorted(l)` looks smart and is elegant, but you'll have to pay the `O(n*log(n))` cost of sorting `l`.
If your goal is to sort `l` if it is not sorted, just directly call `l.sort()`.

Comment: U forgot to put the ending `]` btw

Comment: Add `all` around it, as OP intented it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
comparisons = [l[i] < l[i+1] for i in range(len(l) - 1)]
```

Comment: I also thought similar like `all([l[i] < l[i+1] for i in range(len(l) - 1)])` thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
all(l[x]<l[x+1] for x in range(len(l)-1))
```

Comment: Yes, I saw after posting.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use the .sort() method in which case you'd have to return a new list altogether.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read other answers before answering. This is already answered by @rusu_ro1

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, just joined (new to programming, ~5 months)  and trying to get a feel of the community here.